# Sonar Integration Tests Not showing up using Jacoco + Maven

Tags: java, integration, integration-testing, sonarqube

I just upgraded Sonar server from 3.3.2 to 3.5.  A quick description of our setup: Sonar is using an Oracle database. All plugins have been updated to the latest. The code coverage plugin for java is set to the default (jacoco).  We have configured the dashboard to include Integration Test coverage widget. We use maven to build our java project.

**My maven command is:**
`clean install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Pint-test sonar:sonar -X`

Problem: We cannot seem to get get our project's integration coverage metrics to show up on server dashboard.  However, the build does work with a brand new, base-line, instance of sonar (using embedded database).  To eliminate all variables, I downloaded the sample from [Here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/projects/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-multimodule-maven-jacoco) and performed same test. Still no luck.  I'm at a loss. There seems to be something wrong with the server, but I don't know where else to look. What other configurations could be getting in the way?

Snippets from maven build:

```
[INFO] [14:29:06.065] Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [14:29:06.066] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:06.070] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 4 ms
[INFO] [14:29:06.070] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:06.089] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 19 ms
[INFO] [14:29:06.089] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:06.099] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 10 ms
[INFO] [14:29:06.099] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:06.107] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 8 ms
[INFO] [14:29:06.107] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:06.117] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 10 ms
[INFO] [14:29:06.117] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [14:29:06.130] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 13 ms
[INFO] [14:29:06.581] Execute decorators...
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.581] Decorators: ManualMeasureDecorator -> SumDuplicationsDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@2863866c -> UnitTestDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@1e0e312b -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@444b705e -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@34be4e59 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@27d20642 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@3a09d01c -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@5a3dfc08 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@1b6d9f81 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@3a02dc38 -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ClassesDecorator@4d98eb7a -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionsDecorator@728bbe62 -> org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@34804eae -> FileTangleIndexDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.SuspectLcom4DensityDecorator@17c77736 -> f(lines) -> f(generated_lines) -> f(ncloc) -> f(generated_ncloc) -> f(classes) -> f(packages) -> f(functions) -> f(accessors) -> f(statements) -> f(public_api) -> f(comment_lines) -> f(comment_blank_lines) -> f(public_undocumented_api) -> f(commented_out_code_lines) -> f(complexity) -> f(complexity_in_classes) -> f(complexity_in_functions) -> f(class_complexity_distribution) -> f(lines_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_lines) -> f(conditions_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_conditions) -> f(it_lines_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_lines) -> f(it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_conditions) -> f(rfc) -> f(lcom4) -> f(package_cycles) -> f(package_tangles) -> f(package_feedback_edges) -> f(package_edges_weight) -> f(count_asserts) -> f(eloc) -> f(new_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_it_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions) -> org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@334b49fc -> CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator -> CountFalsePositivesDecorator -> CommentDensityDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ChidamberKemererDistributionBuilder@11c7fe49 -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FileComplexityDistributionDecorator@610773bd -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionComplexityDistributionBuilder@303faf0f -> PackageTangleIndexDecorator -> f(file_complexity) -> f(class_complexity) -> f(function_complexity) -> f(assert_per_test) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@12aea1a2 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@6f59c43 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@66e5f646 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@38ba271 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@4455aa88 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@542ee9c4 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@53f56e09 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@160b3bef -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@3b8bd337 -> f(function_complexity_distribution) -> f(file_complexity_distribution) -> f(rfc_distribution) -> f(lcom4_distribution) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@189d7f93 -> IssuesDensityDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@50661b31 -> VariationDecorator
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.754] Decorator time:
    ManualMeasureDecorator: 9ms
    SumDuplicationsDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@2863866c: 11ms
    UnitTestDecorator: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@1e0e312b: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@444b705e: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@34be4e59: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@27d20642: 8ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@3a09d01c: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@5a3dfc08: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@1b6d9f81: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@3a02dc38: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ClassesDecorator@4d98eb7a: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionsDecorator@728bbe62: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@34804eae: 0ms
    FileTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.SuspectLcom4DensityDecorator@17c77736: 0ms
    f(lines): 0ms
    f(generated_lines): 1ms
    f(ncloc): 0ms
    f(generated_ncloc): 0ms
    f(classes): 0ms
    f(packages): 0ms
    f(functions): 1ms
    f(accessors): 0ms
    f(statements): 0ms
    f(public_api): 0ms
    f(comment_lines): 0ms
    f(comment_blank_lines): 0ms
    f(public_undocumented_api): 0ms
    f(commented_out_code_lines): 0ms
    f(complexity): 0ms
    f(complexity_in_classes): 0ms
    f(complexity_in_functions): 1ms
    f(class_complexity_distribution): 1ms
    f(lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(it_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(it_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(overall_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(rfc): 1ms
    f(lcom4): 0ms
    f(package_cycles): 0ms
    f(package_tangles): 0ms
    f(package_feedback_edges): 0ms
    f(package_edges_weight): 0ms
    f(count_asserts): 0ms
    f(eloc): 0ms
    f(new_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_uncovered_lines): 1ms
    f(new_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(new_it_lines_to_cover): 1ms
    f(new_it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_it_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(new_overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@334b49fc: 0ms
    CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator: 8ms
    CountFalsePositivesDecorator: 1ms
    CommentDensityDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ChidamberKemererDistributionBuilder@11c7fe49: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FileComplexityDistributionDecorator@610773bd: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionComplexityDistributionBuilder@303faf0f: 0ms
    PackageTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
    f(file_complexity): 0ms
    f(class_complexity): 0ms
    f(function_complexity): 0ms
    f(assert_per_test): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@12aea1a2: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@6f59c43: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@66e5f646: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@38ba271: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@4455aa88: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@542ee9c4: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@53f56e09: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@160b3bef: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@3b8bd337: 0ms
    f(function_complexity_distribution): 0ms
    f(file_complexity_distribution): 0ms
    f(rfc_distribution): 0ms
    f(lcom4_distribution): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@189d7f93: 0ms
    IssuesDensityDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@50661b31: 29ms
    VariationDecorator: 88ms

[DEBUG] [14:29:06.755] 65 measures to dump
[INFO] [14:29:06.884] -------------  Scan JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: parent
[INFO] [14:29:06.886] Load module settings
[INFO] [14:29:06.930] Excluded tests: 
[INFO] [14:29:06.930]   **/package-info.java
[INFO] [14:29:06.948] Quality profile : [name=Sonar way,language=java]
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.964] ooo Using Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@idevp-pkg.conseco.com:1521/IDEVP, UserName=xxxx, Oracle JDBC driver]
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.965] ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where id=? 
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.965] ==> Parameters: 21420(Long)
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.971] ooo Using Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@idevp-pkg.conseco.com:1521/IDEVP, UserName=xxxx, Oracle JDBC driver]
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.972] ==>  Preparing: update projects set name=?, long_name=?, description=?, scope=?, qualifier=?, kee=?, language=?, root_id=?, copy_resource_id=?, person_id=?, enabled=? where id=? 
[DEBUG] [14:29:06.973] ==> Parameters: JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: parent(String), JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: parent(String), null, PRJ(String), TRK(String), org.example.app-example:parent(String), java(String), null, null, null, true(Boolean), 21420(Long)
[INFO] [14:29:06.979] Configure Maven plugins
[INFO] [14:29:06.992] Compare to previous analysis (2013-09-17)
[INFO] [14:29:07.000] Compare over 30 days (2013-08-18, analysis of 2013-09-16 09:02:57.248)
[INFO] [14:29:07.003] Compare to previous version
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.052] Initializers : 
[INFO] [14:29:07.053] Base dir: D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test
[INFO] [14:29:07.053] Working dir: D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test\target\sonar
[INFO] [14:29:07.053] Binary dirs: D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test\target\classes
[INFO] [14:29:07.053] Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.056] Sensors : JavaSourceImporter -> JavaSquidSensor -> CpdSensor -> InitialOpenIssuesSensor -> ProfileSensor -> ProfileEventsSensor -> ProjectLinksSensor -> VersionEventsSensor -> Maven dependencies
[INFO] [14:29:07.056] Sensor JavaSourceImporter...
[INFO] [14:29:07.056] Sensor JavaSourceImporter done: 0 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.056] Sensor JavaSquidSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:07.057] Sensor JavaSquidSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.057] Sensor CpdSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:07.057] SonarEngine is used
[INFO] [14:29:07.057] Sensor CpdSensor done: 0 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.057] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:07.060] Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor done: 3 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.060] Sensor ProfileSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:07.081] Sensor ProfileSensor done: 21 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.082] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:07.091] Sensor ProfileEventsSensor done: 8 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.091] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:07.099] Sensor ProjectLinksSensor done: 8 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.099] Sensor VersionEventsSensor...
[INFO] [14:29:07.116] Sensor VersionEventsSensor done: 17 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.117] Sensor Maven dependencies...
[INFO] [14:29:07.125] Sensor Maven dependencies done: 8 ms
[INFO] [14:29:07.413] Execute decorators...
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.414] Decorators: ManualMeasureDecorator -> SumDuplicationsDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@138684e7 -> UnitTestDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@647f63b4 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@6e328cbf -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@38b6881e -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@69eeaa65 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@57a286a8 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@6f36ac8a -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@6e79d110 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@7f8caa19 -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ClassesDecorator@24084dad -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionsDecorator@10c5aa0c -> org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@211f026e -> FileTangleIndexDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.SuspectLcom4DensityDecorator@4341c758 -> f(lines) -> f(generated_lines) -> f(ncloc) -> f(generated_ncloc) -> f(classes) -> f(packages) -> f(functions) -> f(accessors) -> f(statements) -> f(public_api) -> f(comment_lines) -> f(comment_blank_lines) -> f(public_undocumented_api) -> f(commented_out_code_lines) -> f(complexity) -> f(complexity_in_classes) -> f(complexity_in_functions) -> f(class_complexity_distribution) -> f(lines_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_lines) -> f(conditions_to_cover) -> f(uncovered_conditions) -> f(it_lines_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_lines) -> f(it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(overall_uncovered_conditions) -> f(rfc) -> f(lcom4) -> f(package_cycles) -> f(package_tangles) -> f(package_feedback_edges) -> f(package_edges_weight) -> f(count_asserts) -> f(eloc) -> f(new_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_it_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_it_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_it_uncovered_conditions) -> f(new_overall_lines_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_lines) -> f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover) -> f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions) -> org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@5b0d1462 -> CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator -> CountFalsePositivesDecorator -> CommentDensityDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ChidamberKemererDistributionBuilder@6bf390ba -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FileComplexityDistributionDecorator@43a2dab4 -> org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionComplexityDistributionBuilder@78c4821c -> PackageTangleIndexDecorator -> f(file_complexity) -> f(class_complexity) -> f(function_complexity) -> f(assert_per_test) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@357ab823 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@bcf1d43 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@4a8a1fc3 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@322b6170 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@3e0a19cb -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@9237e3f -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@79355ec8 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@1ee1daa3 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@7dd9132b -> f(function_complexity_distribution) -> f(file_complexity_distribution) -> f(rfc_distribution) -> f(lcom4_distribution) -> org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@28471d73 -> IssuesDensityDecorator -> org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@1e33c42c -> VariationDecorator
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.463] Remove data measure from memory: dsm, id=84064336
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.527] Decorator time:
    ManualMeasureDecorator: 2ms
    SumDuplicationsDecorator: 1ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.IssueTrackingDecorator@138684e7: 3ms
    UnitTestDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.security.ApplyProjectRolesDecorator@647f63b4: 4ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.DirectoriesDecorator@6e328cbf: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.FilesDecorator@38b6881e: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TimeMachineConfigurationPersister@69eeaa65: 13ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageFileAnalyzer@57a286a8: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewItCoverageFileAnalyzer@6f36ac8a: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewOverallCoverageFileAnalyzer@6e79d110: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.NewCoverageAggregator@7f8caa19: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ClassesDecorator@24084dad: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionsDecorator@10c5aa0c: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.ProjectDsmDecorator@211f026e: 26ms
    FileTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.design.batch.SuspectLcom4DensityDecorator@4341c758: 0ms
    f(lines): 0ms
    f(generated_lines): 0ms
    f(ncloc): 0ms
    f(generated_ncloc): 0ms
    f(classes): 0ms
    f(packages): 0ms
    f(functions): 1ms
    f(accessors): 0ms
    f(statements): 0ms
    f(public_api): 0ms
    f(comment_lines): 0ms
    f(comment_blank_lines): 0ms
    f(public_undocumented_api): 0ms
    f(commented_out_code_lines): 0ms
    f(complexity): 0ms
    f(complexity_in_classes): 0ms
    f(complexity_in_functions): 0ms
    f(class_complexity_distribution): 0ms
    f(lines_to_cover): 1ms
    f(uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(it_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(it_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(overall_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(rfc): 0ms
    f(lcom4): 0ms
    f(package_cycles): 0ms
    f(package_tangles): 1ms
    f(package_feedback_edges): 0ms
    f(package_edges_weight): 0ms
    f(count_asserts): 0ms
    f(eloc): 0ms
    f(new_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(new_it_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_it_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_it_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_it_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    f(new_overall_lines_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_overall_uncovered_lines): 0ms
    f(new_overall_conditions_to_cover): 0ms
    f(new_overall_uncovered_conditions): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.cpd.decorators.DuplicationDensityDecorator@5b0d1462: 0ms
    CountUnresolvedIssuesDecorator: 2ms
    CountFalsePositivesDecorator: 0ms
    CommentDensityDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.ChidamberKemererDistributionBuilder@6bf390ba: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FileComplexityDistributionDecorator@43a2dab4: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.java.decorators.FunctionComplexityDistributionBuilder@78c4821c: 0ms
    PackageTangleIndexDecorator: 0ms
    f(file_complexity): 0ms
    f(class_complexity): 1ms
    f(function_complexity): 0ms
    f(assert_per_test): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.LineCoverageDecorator@357ab823: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.CoverageDecorator@bcf1d43: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.BranchCoverageDecorator@4a8a1fc3: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItLineCoverageDecorator@322b6170: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItCoverageDecorator@3e0a19cb: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.ItBranchCoverageDecorator@9237e3f: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallLineCoverageDecorator@79355ec8: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallCoverageDecorator@1ee1daa3: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.sensors.OverallBranchCoverageDecorator@7dd9132b: 0ms
    f(function_complexity_distribution): 1ms
    f(file_complexity_distribution): 0ms
    f(rfc_distribution): 0ms
    f(lcom4_distribution): 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.WeightedIssuesDecorator@28471d73: 1ms
    IssuesDensityDecorator: 0ms
    org.sonar.plugins.core.timemachine.TendencyDecorator@1e33c42c: 25ms
    VariationDecorator: 26ms

[DEBUG] [14:29:07.527] 55 measures to dump
[INFO] [14:29:07.781] Store results in database
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.781] Execute org.sonar.batch.index.ComponentDataPersister
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.810] Execute org.sonar.batch.issue.IssuePersister
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.819] Execute org.sonar.batch.phases.GraphPersister
[INFO] [14:29:07.988] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonar.cnoinc.com/dashboard/index/org.example.app-example:parent
[DEBUG] [14:29:07.991] Post-jobs : org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob@23e34760 -> org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob@1e630208 -> org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob@761a6acd
[INFO] [14:29:07.992] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.issue.notification.SendIssueNotificationsPostJob
[INFO] [14:29:07.993] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.core.batch.IndexProjectPostJob
[INFO] [14:29:08.190] Executing post-job class org.sonar.plugins.dbcleaner.ProjectPurgePostJob
[INFO] [14:29:08.221] -> Keep one snapshot per day between 2013-08-20 and 2013-09-16
[INFO] [14:29:08.224] -> Keep one snapshot per week between 2012-09-18 and 2013-08-20
[INFO] [14:29:08.225] -> Keep one snapshot per month between 2008-09-23 and 2012-09-18
[INFO] [14:29:08.226] -> Delete data prior to: 2008-09-23
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.228] ooo Using Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@idevp-pkg.conseco.com:1521/IDEVP, UserName=xxx, Oracle JDBC driver]
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.228] ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where id=? 
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.229] ==> Parameters: 21420(Long)
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.234] ooo Using Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@idevp-pkg.conseco.com:1521/IDEVP, UserName=xxxx, Oracle JDBC driver]
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.234] ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=? 
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.234] ==> Parameters: 21420(Long)
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.240] ooo Using Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@idevp-pkg.conseco.com:1521/IDEVP, UserName=xxx, Oracle JDBC driver]
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.241] ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=? 
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.241] ==> Parameters: 21421(Long)
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.242] ooo Using Connection [jdbc:oracle:thin:@idevp-pkg.conseco.com:1521/IDEVP, UserName=xxx, Oracle JDBC driver]
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.243] ==>  Preparing: select * from projects where scope='PRJ' and root_id=? 
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.243] ==> Parameters: 21422(Long)
[INFO] [14:29:08.245] -> Clean JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: parent [id=21420]
[INFO] [14:29:08.261] <- Clean snapshot 1913186
[INFO] [14:29:08.474] -> Clean JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app [id=21421]
[INFO] [14:29:08.481] -> Clean JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app-it [id=21422]
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.518] Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@5568a50f[id=21420,key=org.example.app-example:parent,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-org.example.app-example:parent
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.574] To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] has been forcibly deregistered
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.708] Delete temporary directory: C:\Windows\TEMP\sonar-batch593076914431310978418791515580052
[DEBUG] [14:29:08.747] Delete temporary directory: C:\Windows\TEMP\sonar-batch6488372037625931143417068002613460
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: Reactor Summary:
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: 
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: parent .......... SUCCESS [36.562s]
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app ............. SUCCESS [10.357s]
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logReactorSummary
INFO: JaCoCo Examples :: app-example :: app-it .......... SUCCESS [1.968s]
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logResult
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logResult
INFO: BUILD SUCCESS
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logStats
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logStats
INFO: Total time: 1:00.495s
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:08 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logStats
INFO: Finished at: Tue Sep 17 14:29:08 EDT 2013
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:09 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger logStats
INFO: Final Memory: 28M/189M
Sep 17, 2013 2:29:09 PM org.apache.maven.cli.event.ExecutionEventLogger sessionEnded
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test\app\pom.xml to D:\Jenkins\jobs\Sonar IT Test\modules\org.example.app-example$app\builds\2013-09-17_14-28-03\archive\org.example.app-example\app\1.0-SNAPSHOT\app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test\app\target\app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to D:\Jenkins\jobs\Sonar IT Test\modules\org.example.app-example$app\builds\2013-09-17_14-28-03\archive\org.example.app-example\app\1.0-SNAPSHOT\app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test\app-it\pom.xml to D:\Jenkins\jobs\Sonar IT Test\modules\org.example.app-example$app-it\builds\2013-09-17_14-28-03\archive\org.example.app-example\app-it\1.0-SNAPSHOT\app-it-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test\app-it\target\app-it-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to D:\Jenkins\jobs\Sonar IT Test\modules\org.example.app-example$app-it\builds\2013-09-17_14-28-03\archive\org.example.app-example\app-it\1.0-SNAPSHOT\app-it-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\Jenkins\workspace\Sonar IT Test\pom.xml to D:\Jenkins\jobs\Sonar IT Test\modules\org.example.app-example$parent\builds\2013-09-17_14-28-03\archive\org.example.app-example\parent\1.0-SNAPSHOT\parent-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
channel stopped
No emails were triggered.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: What if you run "mvn clean install" first and then "mvn sonar:sonar"? Still the same issue with both the project sample and your own project?

Comment: Same result. No change....

Comment: David- Let me know if you want to see the full output/log.

Comment: Sure. The one of the project sample.

Comment: Wasn't able to paste in the full log. I pasted in that last part of the jenkins output.

Comment: How likely is it, that the problem is with using Sonar with Oracle?  What is the suggested db, that works best with Sonar?  Does the new log above help in pointing out the problem?

Comment: SonarQube works well with Oracle. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Requirements.

Comment: Don't know how to help you further... There must be something specific on your instance but I don't know what.

Comment: Any tips on how I could go about troubleshooting this?